# Error Configuring Spring + Hibernate Application

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup a basic template for a spring/hibernate application. I have never done this before so I do not really know what the problem is. Here is the error output and a link to the code. I think it is trying to auto configure instead of reading my spring.xml file.

link: https://github.com/cfeher/Party-App/tree/0.0.x/Api

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

spring.xml

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">



            <!-- Hibernate 3 Annotation SessionFactory Bean definition-->
                <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
                    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mobiengineering"/>
                    <property name="hibernateProperties">
                        <value>
                            hbm2ddl.auto=create
                            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                            hibernate.show_sql=true             
                        </value>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
                    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
                    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"/>
                    <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
                    <property name="password" value=""/>
                </bean>


                <bean id="personDAO" class="org.mobiengineering.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
                    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
                </bean>

            </beans>
```

pom.xml

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
                <artifactId>SpringHibernateExample</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <properties>

                    <!-- Generic properties -->
                    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
                    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

                    <!-- Spring -->
                    <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

                    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
                    <!-- <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version> -->
                    <hibernate.version>3.6.9.Final</hibernate.version>

                    <!-- Logging -->
                    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
                    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

                </properties>

                <parent>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
                </parent>


                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                            <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Spring ORM support -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
                        <scope>compile</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        <version>${logback.version}</version>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependency>

                    <!-- Hibernate -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                        <version>5.1.9</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                        <version>1.4</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

                <repositories>
                    <repository>
                        <id>spring-releases</id>
                        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                    </repository>
                </repositories>
                <pluginRepositories>
                    <pluginRepository>
                        <id>spring-releases</id>
                        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
                    </pluginRepository>
                </pluginRepositories>
            </project>
```

Comment: post your configuration file, it is complaining that you dint put driverClassName

Comment: 1) do you (want) to use spring boot?

Comment: 2) please post your pom.xml

Comment: If you click the link you can see all of the files. I figured linking the github would be easier.

Comment: I don't think spring.xml is being read correctly... Autoconfigure seems to be doing its own thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the following class annotation to Application.java:

```
@ImportResource(value = {"/spring.xml"})
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
     ...
}
```

`@ComponentScan` only auto-detects Spring Components stereotype annotations. For xml, you will have to add `@ImportResource`.

Also:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
context.close();
```

those line above are redundant: Application.class, args);` is sufficient for spring boot to boot your application.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use spring boot, just comment the line above (i.e. `SpringApplication.run(...)`)